# Why does my app run much faster on my laptop than my VPS?

Tags: webserver, ruby, vps, cpu-speed

I have a web application with a Ruby backend that does some stuff that is a bit computationally intensive.  I develop and test the app on my rMBP with a 2.7GHz i7.  I have the app deployed to a Linode VPS with 6 cores (Intel Xeon E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz which, as of this writing, is a fast server processor) and SSD storage (the 8GB/8192) plan.  There aren't any other apps running on the Linode at this point.  My application is about 10X faster on my laptop.  Why might that be true?  It is killing me and my clients aren't happy.

Comment: My guess it's the VPS configration at fault

Comment: You wrote it, debug it and figure out where your bottleneck(s) are. Why it might be slow is way too broad of a question for us to answer.

Comment: The problem isn't my code, it is the hardware (virtualized or otherwise) running the code.  Changing my code isn't the solution.  What Techie007 is suggesting is analogous to trying to alter my car because I am stuck in a traffic jam.  I would like to understand traffic jams, where, why, and when they occur, so that I can make better choices about the types of driving environments I drive my car in in the future.